# Identifying the Right Spring Boot Starter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

I wanted to build a Application which listens to a queue and does a series of steps. 
Basically the application should listen to Queue1 and:
 - Get some data from ServiceA[Small amount of data]
 - Get some data from ServiceB[Small amount of data]
 - Update Some information in Service C [Based on the data]
 - Create number of messages[based on the data] on a Queue2.

Due to the flow based nature of this application I was looking into Job Execution system in Spring. However all the steps are designed to be idempotent and the data being transferred between steps is small, hence I did not want a Database with this application.

I started exploring Spring Batch or Spring Task for this. Spring batch provides really good constructs like Tasklet and Steps but there are number of comments recommending connecting Spring Batch to database and how it is designed to manage massive amounts of data, reliably(I don't need reliability here since the queue and idempotent nature provides that.). While I can pass data using the Execution Context there were recommendations against it.

Question:
 - Are there simpler starters in the Spring Boot ecosystem which provide workflows/Job like interface which I should use ?
 - Is this a valid use case for spring Batch or is that over engineering/misuse of the steps ?

Thanks a lot for the Help
Ayushman

P.S: I can provide exact details of the job but did not want to conflate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two projects worth of experience with Spring Batch. I haven't tried Spring Task.

Having said that, my answer is somewhat bias. Spring Batch is a bit notorious to configure. If your application is simple enough, just use "spring-boot-starter-amqp". It will be enough.

By any chance, you decide to use Spring Batch (for its Job and Step Aspects features or other features), you may want to configure to just use an in-memory database (because you don't need any retry/roll-back feature it is providing).

Comment: Thanks ! I followed you advice.